# Group array objects by properties

Tags: php

How to group array by 'tax'and 'concept' and SUM attribute 'val'?

I looking for create a single object when tax and concept are the same, also SUM the val.

I tried with simple foreach and validation inside, but doesnt work.

thanks.

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

**Array Print**

```
[
 {
    "tax": "10",
    "concept": "TUC",
    "val": "10"
 },
 {
    "tax": "10",
    "concept": "TUC",
    "val": "86"
 },
 {
    "tax": "15",
    "concept": "TUC",
    "val": "8"
 },
 {
    "tax": "11",
    "concept": "IPS",
    "val": "6"
 },
 {
    "tax": "11",
    "concept": "IPS",
    "val": "45"
 }  
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
 {
    "tax": "10",
    "concept": "TUC",
    "val": "96"
 },
 {
    "tax": "15",
    "concept": "TUC",
    "val": "8"
 },
 {
    "tax": "11",
    "concept": "IPS",
    "val": "51"
 }
]
```

Comment: *I tried with simple foreach and validation inside, but doesnt work.* - show your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) here. You'll use the `tax` value as a key you're grouping on, and reduce the array to unique `tax` elements while simultaneously producing the sum of `val` values. The only caveat with this approach is that transforming it to JSON will make PHP think that the outer element is an object and not an array (even though it is an array, this is because we end up using non-default array indexing). But, this is easily mitigated with a call to [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values).

```
$array = // your array from above
$result = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) { 
    if(!isset($carry[$item->tax])) {
        $carry[$item->tax] = $item;
    } else {
        $carry[$item->tax]->val += $item->val;
    }
    return $carry;
});

$result = array_values($result);

echo json_encode($result);
```

You can see from [this demo](https://3v4l.org/ndnbQ) that it produces:

```
[{
    "tax": "10",
    "concept": "TUC",
    "val": 96
}, {
    "tax": "15",
    "concept": "TUC",
    "val": "8"
}, {
    "tax": "11",
    "concept": "IPS",
    "val": 51
}]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, plus, you are considering the value of `tax` as the key. The OP wants to group when **both** `tax` and `concept` are the same, so the key should be a combination of those two.

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera - That's why there's a demo link, to try it and see that it works. Also, the OP's data doesn't have any values where that key would be required (when tax matches another element, so does its concept), but it's a simple modification that can be left to the OP to implement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array // Your array 
$result = [];

array_walk($array, function($object) use (&$result) {
    $notExist = true;
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        if ($item->tax == $object->tax && $item->concept == $object->concept) {
            $item->val += $object->val;
            $notExist = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($notExist) {
        array_push($result, $object);
    }
});

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First group the objects:

```
$groups = [];
foreach($array as $object){
    $groups[$object->tax . "\0" . $object->concept] = $object;
    // I use the NUL byte to delimit, assuming it is absent in $tax and $concept
}
```

Then map each group into a summed-up object.

```
$output = array_map(function(array $group){
    $object = new stdClass;
    $object->tax = $group[0]->tax;
    $object->concept = $group[0]->concept;
    $object->val = array_reduce($group, function($carry, $item){
        return $carry + $item->val;
    }, 0);
    return $object;
}, $groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr_str = '[
    {"tax":"10", "concept":"TUC", "val":"10"},
    {"tax":"10", "concept":"TUC", "val":"86"},
    {"tax":"15", "concept":"TUC", "val":"8"},
    {"tax":"11", "concept":"IPS", "val":"6"},
    {"tax":"11", "concept":"IPS", "val":"45"}
]';

$arr = json_decode($arr_str);

$tmp_array = [];

foreach ($arr as $e) {
    // combine "tax" and "concept" so we can use both of them as key. Use "_" as delimiter.
    $key = $e->tax . "_" . $e->concept;
    // sum the "val" if the key exists, otherwise assign it
    isset($tmp_array[$key]) ? $tmp_array[$key] += $e->val : $tmp_array[$key] = $e->val;
}

$grouped_array = [];

foreach ($tmp_array as $k => $v) {
    // ungroup the key so we can create an array like the original one
    $tmp = explode("_", $k);
    $grouped_array[] = (object)["tax" => $tmp[0], "concept" => $tmp[1], "val" => $v];
}

echo json_encode($grouped_array);
?>
```